# jhipster-entity-audit threw exception when i try enable audit

Tags: jhipster, yo

jhipster-entity-audit threw exception when i try enable audit, exception:

```
    Reading the JHipster project configuration for your module
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: jhipsterFunc.copyTemplate is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> 
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at copyFiles 
    at module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.writing.writeBaseFiles 
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    at npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-entity-audit\node_modules\ye
nc\index.js:24:25
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I find issue about this problem [generator-jhipster-entity-audit](https://github.com/deepu105/generator-jhipster-entity-audit/issues/3), but i begginer in npm.

Please tell me the best solution to this problem

**UPD:**

I trying download generator-jhipster from this [repo](https://github.com/deepu105/generator-jhipster) and now i have problem when starting jhipster-entity-audit:

```
Error jhipster-entity-audit
You don't seem to have a generator with the name jhipster:modules installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 9 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the deepu's repo, which is a fork

Use the official or install the latest version of generator-jhipster 2.27.0

Comment: on the official version, there was an error from first part of question

Comment: I dont think you are using the latest official version, this error is only when you use an older Jhipster version. this will work only with Jhipster 2.27

Comment: do npm install -g generator-jhipster first then try running the module, did you follow the instruction on the readme file?